# webdriver error with sso form

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to automate my access and do some scrapping on a french website.
(http://espaceclientcanal.canal-plus.com/aide/pid792-s-inscrire-sur-l-espace-client.html).

I have a valid account but I cannot login with selenium.
I have managed to grab elements with xpath expressions or with code like this :

```
browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id('sso-email')).sendKeys('mymail@org.com');
//var emailField = browser.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//input[@id='sso-email']")) ;
```

I also used the following function to make sure an element exists :

```
function isElementPresent(driver, by){
    try{
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    }catch(NoSuchElementException){
      return false;
    }
}
```

Init my webdriver like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({ 'browserName': 'chrome' }).build();
```

Each time I get the following error:

> NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="sso-email"]"}   (Session
>   info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520
>   (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

I'm confident on my xpath expression (maybe I'm wrong)...

I do not understand what the error is.

The login form seems to be generated as a component (a progress wheel is displayed first) ; would it be possible that this is specifically designed to prevent automations scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Selenium code looks good but incomplete.

The login form is placed inside an `iframe` with `name="pass_iframe"`.

So, before finding the email and password fields, you need to get the iframe from the page, switch to it, indentify the login elements and perform the login and then switch back to the main page.

```
var iframe  = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath('iframe[name='pass_iframe']'));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
//find the login elements
//do the login
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```